# Re-implement Debug trait for a third-party struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I have an autogenerated `struct` named `Address` by protobuf in Rust. It has a predefined `Debug` trait like this:

```
impl ::std::fmt::Debug for Address {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut ::std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
        ::protobuf::text_format::fmt(self, f)
    }
}
```

But I want to customize how it's printed when `{:#?}` is used. So I decided to implement `Debug` trait for it like this in my project:

```
impl fmt::Debug for EvmProto::Address {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
      ....
    }
}
```

But it complains that `` conflicting implementations of trait `std::fmt::Debug` for type `protos::Evm::Address ``

Comment: What crate are you using for protobuf?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `protobuf = { version = "2.27.1",  features = ["with-bytes"] }`

Comment: Your options appear to be (1) somehow tell the code generator not to emit a `Debug` implementation, (2) post-process the generated code to remove the `Debug` implementation or (3) use a newtype wrapper around `Address`. I'm not familar with the protobuf code generator, so I don't know whether (1) is an option at all.

Comment: Can you include the protobuf declaration?

Comment: From looking at the source code, it seems protobuf does not have a way to not emit `#[derive(Debug)]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman ```message Address {
  fixed32 x0 = 1;
  fixed64 x1 = 2;
  fixed64 x2 = 3;
}```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: while the answer can still be useful in some similar cases, in this case it seems incorrect. See the comments for details.

You can't implement an external trait on an external type.

I'm citing [The Rust Book](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch10-02-traits.html)

> we can’t implement external traits on external types. For example, we can’t implement the `Display` trait on `Vec<T>` within our aggregator crate, because `Display` and `Vec<T>` are both defined in the standard library and aren’t local to our aggregator crate. This restriction is part of a property called coherence, and more specifically the orphan rule, so named because the parent type is not present. This rule ensures that other people’s code can’t break your code and vice versa. Without the rule, two crates could implement the same trait for the same type, and Rust wouldn’t know which implementation to use.

Comment: `Address` is not an external type. It's a type generated by a proc macro, but the proc macro also generates a `Debug` implementation.

Comment: Apparently, it's a code generator, not a proc macro, but that doesn't change much.

Comment: So, what the reason for the error? Not that the trait or type is external, but rather that the implementation can't be overwritten, right?

Comment: Yeah, you can't have two implementations of the same trait for the same type. Which one is the compiler supposed to take?